# retrieve table from a web service to wp7 page

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

Is there any way to retrieve a table from  a web service to a wp7 app page as its?
 i just wanna sth easy to use than making a table each time getting data

Comment: Did you mean HTML web table or what please?

Comment: XML table. the web service show a table i want the same table to view in my wp7 page . and how can i save the element value in array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have look on MSDN for System.Xml namespace. It contains lot of usable classes. You should use XmlReader or something similair to load it to array or generic collection. Hope this helps, 'cause bit unclear question.

**EDIT:**

This is the code what have I done for loading sample data to generic collection:

Sample data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <studentPunishmentsTables>
  <studentPunishmentsTable>
    <fromSemester/>
    <fromSemesterDesc/>
    <issueDate>01/04/2012</issueDate>
    <note/>
    <penalty>Course Failure</penalty>
    <semester>311</semester>
    <semesterDesc>First Semester 31/32</semesterDesc>
    <toSemester/>
    <toSemesterDesc/>
  </studentPunishmentsTable>
  <studentPunishmentsTable>
    <fromSemester/>
    <fromSemesterDesc/>
    <issueDate>01/04/2012</issueDate>
    <note/>
    <penalty>Semester Failure</penalty>
    <semester>311</semester>
    <semesterDesc>First Semester 31/32</semesterDesc>
    <toSemester/>
    <toSemesterDesc/>
  </studentPunishmentsTable>
</studentPunishmentsTables>
```

Code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.IO;

namespace XMLStudent
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load("st.xml");
            List<StudentPunishment> sp = new List<StudentPunishment>();
            foreach (XmlNode nod in doc.SelectNodes(@"studentPunishmentsTables/studentPunishmentsTable"))
            {
                StudentPunishment s = new StudentPunishment();
                s.FromSemester = nod.ChildNodes[0].InnerText;
                s.FromSemesterDesc = nod.ChildNodes[1].InnerText;
                s.IssueDate = nod.ChildNodes[2].InnerText;
                s.Note = nod.ChildNodes[3].InnerText;
                s.Penalty = nod.ChildNodes[4].InnerText;
                s.Semester = nod.ChildNodes[5].InnerText;
                s.SemesterDesc = nod.ChildNodes[6].InnerText;
                s.ToSemester = nod.ChildNodes[7].InnerText;
                s.ToSemesterDesc = nod.ChildNodes[8].InnerText;
                sp.Add(s);
            }
            Console.WriteLine(sp[0].IssueDate);
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
    class StudentPunishment
    {
        public string FromSemester { get; set; }
        public string FromSemesterDesc { get; set; }
        public string IssueDate { get; set; }
        public string Note { get; set; }
        public string Penalty { get; set; }
        public string Semester { get; set; }
        public string SemesterDesc { get; set; }
        public string ToSemester { get; set; }
        public string ToSemesterDesc { get; set; }
    }
}
```

So. This code is loading XMLDocument with sample data and it's selecting data of each studentPunishmentsTable into new object of StudentPunishment class. There're properties for holding that data. After everything is done and object of student's punishment is added into generic collection ('List'), code is trying to show date of first object in collection. You can test is yourself, it's working for me.

Comment: i mean how i can put the tables value in array which i retrieve from a web service

Comment: If I understand it, you're receiving XML table as the response from web. So you need to use XmlReader to load it to array? 'm I right?

Comment: yes that true but i dont know how to put them in array when load?

Comment: we cannot help you 'cause I dont know your table's structure. Please paste here some piece of example data that you need to parse into array.

Comment: <studentPunishmentsTables>
<studentPunishmentsTable>
<fromSemester/>
<fromSemesterDesc/>
<issueDate>01/04/2012</issueDate>
<note/>
<penalty>Course Failure</penalty>
<semester>311</semester>
<semesterDesc>First Semester 31/32</semesterDesc>
<toSemester/>
<toSemesterDesc/>
</studentPunishmentsTable>
<studentPunishmentsTable>
<fromSemester/>
<fromSemesterDesc/>
<issueDate>01/04/2012</issueDate>
<note/>
<penalty>Semester Failure</penalty>
<semester>311</semester>
<semesterDesc>First Semester 31/32</semesterDesc>
<toSemester/>
<toSemesterDesc/>
</studentPunishmentsTable>
</studentPunishmentsTables>

Comment: the array should include a tables..??. i'm sry but really i tried many ways but nothing work...

Comment: studentPunishmentsTables content is a  studentPunishmentsTable

Comment: I'l make it in OOP. I'll try to make it as fast as is possible (about 14:00 GTM+2 to wait)

Comment: thanx alot i know i'm annoying but the childNodes and selectnodes XmlNdes have no definitions and when i used the ( @"studentPunishmentsTables/studentPunishmentsTable") gives me error that cant use "/" in names :( anyway thanx alot for your time i used some notes of this code it's worked but still i have a problem when showing the values it show me the value of the first table in two times although the program read the second table value but dosent show it

Comment: because it's not in code. In that error of selecting nodes, try to replace '/' with '\' (forwardslash with backwardslash). 

If I've helped you, please click accept after this answer.
If you have another problem, please edit question, ro contact me on frewcen@gmail.com .

Comment: i did but still same error if that possible to send you my code on ur mail??